# Trying to create plugin/shortcode for WordPress Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress, carousel

I am trying to create a plugin for my theme to use a custom post type "carousel-images"
and the shortcode [carousel] to create a carousel of featured images.

Currently the first image shows up with the Bootstrap Carousel navigation and prev/next icons, but the carousel will not scroll or show any additional images. There are 3 posts with featured images for the carousel.

here is my plugin.php

```
<?php
        /*
        Plugin Name: WP_BS_Carousel
        Description: Bootstrap Carousel Custom Post-Type
        Author: Jaycbrf4
        Version: 1.0
        /*/


        function wp_bs_theme_setup() {
           add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  
            add_image_size( 'wp_bs_carousel_image', 1170, 385, true);
        }
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wp_bs_theme_setup' );



        // Creates Carousel Image Custom Post Type
            add_action( 'init', 'register_wp_bs_carousel_image' );
            function register_wp_bs_carousel_image() {
            $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Carousel Images', 'carousel_image' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Carousel Image', 'carousel_image' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'carousel_image' ),
            'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Carousel Image', 'carousel_image' ),
            'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Carousel Image', 'carousel_image' ),
            'new_item' => _x( 'New Carousel Image', 'carousel_image' ),
            'view_item' => _x( 'View Carousel Image', 'carousel_image' ),
            'search_items' => _x( 'Search Carousel Images', 'carousel_image' ),
            'not_found' => _x( 'No carousel images found', 'carousel_image' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No carousel images found in Trash', 'carousel_image' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Carousel Image:', 'carousel_image' ),
            'menu_name' => _x( 'Carousel Images', 'carousel_image' ),
            );
            $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'description' => 'Images for Bootsrap Carousel',
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt',
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
            );
            register_post_type( 'carousel-image', $args );
            } 



        function wp_bs_carousel($atts) {
           // Set Shortcode Attributes
           extract(shortcode_atts(array(
              'posts' => 1,
           ), $atts));

           // Start the Return String
           $return_string = '<div id="wp_bs_carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade"  data-ride="carousel">

           <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators" >
            <li data-target="#wp_bs_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#wp_bs_carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#wp_bs_carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>


         <div class="carousel-inner" >';

           // The query
           $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
           'post_type' => 'carousel-image',
            'posts_per_page' => 1
            ));

           // The loop
           while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
              $the_query->the_post();
              $return_string .= '<div class="item active">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'wp_bs_carousel_image').'<div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
            <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
           </div>
           </div><!-- item active -->';
           endwhile;
           wp_reset_postdata();
           $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post-type' => 'carousel-image',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts,
            'offset' => 1
            ));
           while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
           $the_query->the_post();
          $return_string  .= '<div class="item">'.the_post_thumbnail('wp_bs_carousel_image').'<div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>'.the_title().'</h1>
            <p>'.the_excerpt().'</p>
           </div>
           </div><!-- item -->';
           endwhile;
           wp_reset_postdata();

           // Finish the Return String and Clean Up
           $return_string .= '</div>

             <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#wp_bs_carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#wp_bs_carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>';

           return $return_string;
        }

        add_shortcode('carousel', 'wp_bs_carousel');


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posts per page are set to 1, try -1 to get all or whatever amount you want to limit it to.  Also, you're fixing the number of indicators as three.  You'll probably need to do a count and then loop to build the HTML for the indicators.

In your loop, you're setting all items to have the active class which might cause a problem for bootstrap.

(source, literally just did built the exact same thing :) )

Comment: If I change posts per page to -1, all the images stack below the first.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query to :

```
// The query
       $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_type' => 'carousel-image',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        ));
        $i = 0;
       // The loop
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
          $the_query->the_post();
            if ( $i == 0 ) {
          $return_string .= '<div class="item active">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'wp_bs_carousel_image').'<div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
        <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
       </div>
       </div><!-- item active -->';
          } else {
            $return_string .= '<div class="item">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'wp_bs_carousel_image').'<div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>
        <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
       </div>
       </div><!-- item -->';
            }
            $i++;
       endwhile;
       wp_reset_postdata();

       // Finish the Return String and Clean Up
```

That was the ticket- Now I just need to adjust the indicators to count how many slides are in the category carousel-images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$the_query->found_posts

after your query.

Comment: Not sure what that will do... Here is my current code: http://pastebin.com/vSfP56S0